# How can we unset messages in magento 2?

Tags: checkout, cart

```
$result->setMessage(
                sprintf(
                    $this->helper->getCartMessage(),
                    $this->stockStatus->getStockItem()->getProductName(),
                    $this->backordersQty * 1
                )
            );
```

I want to unset/remove this notice message from the cart. How can I do that?

Comment: $result->setMessage(
                    sprintf(
                        '',
                        $this->stockStatus->getStockItem()->getProductName(),
                        $this->backordersQty * 1
                    )
                );

This is the code i have tried. but showing the blank notice design.

Comment: you dont need any messages to display ?

Comment: Yes, I just try this $result->setMessage(NULL);

Answer (score 0):

Here I just add the below code for show null message without notice design.

```
$result->setMessage(NULL);
```